# Best Practise to Add Custom Tab in Product Details (backend)

Tags: product, adminhtml, magento-1, backend, best-practice

I would like to add an extra tab to the product details ( backend ) and I don't want to perform any override, if possible.

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally I would go for a layout/action approach using the `addTab()` provided by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs`

So 2 main action are involved here:

1. add XML layout changes
2. create the tab class
3. ( all this can be accomplish creating a new module, out of the scope here )

**-- 1. Layout changes --**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
     <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <block type="MODULENAME/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab" name="custom_tab"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>Custom Tab</name>
                <block>custom_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

**-- 2. Tab Class --**

```
<?php
class NAMESPACE_MODULENAME_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Custom Tab');
    }
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Custom Tab');
    }
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/customtab', array('_current' => true));
    }
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return 'ajax';
    }
}
```

**Note:**
There is very few documentation about backend development, I feel like Magento Devs. are kind of shy to share knowledge about this area (and that is why of the above question.)

**Source:**
This technique can be found here:
  - http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/02/create-custom-tab-in-magento-product-addedit-page.html
and also in the comments of this Inchoo article:
  - http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it.

Create an observer for the event `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after`. Not sure if it's the best event though.

```
<adminhtml>
    ...
    <events>
       <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
            <observers>
                <[namespace]_[module]_product>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>[module]/adminhtml_observer</class>
                    <method>addProductTabBlock</method>
                </[namespace]_[module]_product>
            </observers>
       </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
    ....
</adminhtml>
```

Then create the observer

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Adminhtml_Observer {
    //this checks if the tab can be added. You don't want to add the tab when selecting the product type and attribute set or when selecting the configurable attributes.
    protected function _canAddTab($product){
        if ($product->getId()){
            return true;
        }
        if (!$product->getAttributeSetId()){
            return false;
        }
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        if ($request->getParam('type') == 'configurable'){
            if ($request->getParam('attributes')){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //the method that actually adds the tab
    public function addProductTabBlock($observer){
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        $product = Mage::registry('product');
        //if on product tabs block and the tab can be added...
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs && $this->_canAddTab($product)){
            //in case there is an ajax tab
            $block->addTab('some_identifier_here', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Some Label here'),

                'url'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/some_url/here', array('_current' => true)),
                'class' => 'ajax', 
            ));
            //in case it's a simple content tab
            $block->addTab('other_identifier_here', array(
                 'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Label here'),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[module]/block_alias')->toHtml(),
            )); 
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Just make sure you replace `[namespace]` and `[module]` with the values you have for your module.

Comment: this is not a best practice

Comment: @Fra I didn't say it is. The answer started with "Here is how I do it.". And it works. Feel free to challange it, change it or come with a better alternative.

Comment: it is good to have this approach so we can collect all possible solution in this page. ( check my answer for a more "Magento" way )

Comment: @Fra. Interesting. I will try it.

Comment: @Marius, i want to create a new menu like catalog->manage products.
Is there any way to perform.Exact copy of catalog->manage products.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your `config.xml` file

```
<blocks>
...
    <modulename>
        <class>Company_ModuleName_Block</class>
    </modulename>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
             <catalog_product_edit_tabs>Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs</catalog_product_edit_tabs>
         </rewrite>
     </adminhtml>
...
</blocks>
```

After this you should create a new file: `Company/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Tabs.php`

```
<?php

class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
{
    private $parent;

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        //get all existing tabs
        $this->parent = parent::_prepareLayout();
        //add new tab
        $this->addTab('tabid', array(
                     'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Tab'),
                     'content'   => $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_tabs_tabid')->toHtml(),
        ));
        return $this->parent;
    }
}
```

Next,  create a file: `Company/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Tabs/Tabid.php`

```
<?php

class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Tabid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('modulename/newtab.phtml');
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php

) and add the following snippet to the function `_prepareLayout()`

```
$this->addTab('tabid', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Tab'),
              'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
     ->createBlock('modulname/adminhtml_tabs_tabid')->toHtml()),
));
```

You can always create a local of any core file.

Comment: rewrite was not welcome, anyway it is good to have this approach so we have all possible solution here

Comment: We can always avoid rewriting by creating a local, anyways when you have your personal favorite, its better to proceed with that. Good Luck

Comment: this last answer is really not good ... local should only used as last solution, it is really worst than use a rewrite

Comment: Please suggest how is creating a local worse the rewrite?

Comment: have you ever upgrade magento ? local should never used, this is best practice ... local is almost like edit core file.

Comment: The question was not why local should not be used, but it was how rewrite is better then local?

Comment: you are welcome to open a question here on magento.stackexchange ... I guess it is a good question

Comment: I did and this is what i get:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25763/core-local-which-is-better#25765