# Magento search return only products containing both words

Tags: magento-1, search, catalogsearch

If a customer searches for "black dress" my current search results includes products with word "black" OR "dress" OR "black dress".

How can I only show products that have both words: "black" AND "dress"?

I tried to change the search type: like, fulltext, combine. Neither worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind that Magento's search is lame. You can either override the search controller to your likings or use a 3rd party extension for research. Either [Lucene](https://php4u.co.uk/blast-search-lucene-magento-extension/) or [Solr](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-bridge-search.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the method `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::prepareResult` there is this code that splits the query string into words and generates a `where` condition, but it works only in `like` or `combine` mode.

```
        if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE
            || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
        ) {
            $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
            $words = Mage::helper('core/string')->splitWords($queryText, true, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
            foreach ($words as $word) {
                $like[] = $helper->getCILike('s.data_index', $word, array('position' => 'any'));
            }
            if ($like) {
                $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
            }
        }
```

Notice this line:

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
```

You can rewrite the class and method and replace that line with

```
 $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
```

Comment: 37s Marius! I'll beat you next time!

Comment: @Richard...Never...(insert evil laugh here). :) And a +1 from be for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: This is brilliant @Marius. I've been using the Catalog Search Refinement plugin by Activo for 2 years and have decided to test upgrading my store to version 1.9.3.4 - unfortunately, they haven't made the plugin compatible with this version of Magento so this quick fix has helped me a lot.

Comment: @Marius But sir it will not work for me

Answer (score 3):

`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php` has a function called `prepareResult()` that has a line that looks a bit like `$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';` You need that OR to be AND if you want both terms to be required. You could

1. *BAD* edit `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php` to change it
2. *LESS BAD* copy it to `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php` and change it there
3. *EVEN LESS BAD* Extend `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` with your own class and rewrite the class magento uses

Comment: Thanks! Why is the second one considered bad? Are there some adverse effects?

Comment: @Claudiu. This is why is bad: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25767/146