# Magento cannot override Sales_Model_Order_Api.php file

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, sales-order, model

I am trying to override `Sales/Model/Order/Api.php` file. but it going to core file. and i am getting that `sales_order_api` in rewrite collection with below script

```
 <?php
    $folders = array('app/code/local/', 'app/code/community/');//folders to parse
    $configFiles = array();
    foreach ($folders as $folder){
        $files = glob($folder.'*/*/etc/config.xml');//get all config.xml files in the specified folder
        $configFiles = array_merge($configFiles, $files);//merge with the rest of the config files
    }
    $rewrites = array();//list of all rewrites

    foreach ($configFiles as $file){
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXML(file_get_contents($file));
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $path = '//rewrite/*';//search for tags named 'rewrite'
            $text = $xpath->query($path);
            foreach ($text as $rewriteElement){
                $type = $rewriteElement->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->tagName;//what is overwritten (model, block, helper)
                $parent = $rewriteElement->parentNode->parentNode->tagName;//module identifier that is being rewritten (core, catalog, sales, ...)
                $name = $rewriteElement->tagName;//element that is rewritten (layout, product, category, order)
                foreach ($rewriteElement->childNodes as $element){
                    $rewrites[$type][$parent.'/'.$name][] = $element->textContent;//class that rewrites it
                }
            }
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($rewrites);
  ?>
```

Output is

```
Array
  (
   [models] => Array
    (
        [cataloginventory/stock_item_api_v2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Example_Webservices_Model_Cataloginventory_Api_V2
            )

        [sales/order_api] => Array
            (
                [0] => Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api
            )

        [core_mysql4/session] => Array
            (
                [0] => Cm_RedisSession_Model_Session
            )

    )

)
```

The script is:

`config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Example_Webservices>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </Example_Webservices>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
      <connector>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Example_Webservices</module>
            <frontName>test</frontName>
          </args>
      </connector>
    </routers>
 </frontend>

<global>
    <models>
         <cataloginventory>
             <rewrite>
                 <stock_item_api_v2>Example_Webservices_Model_Cataloginventory_Api_V2</stock_item_api_v2>
             </rewrite>
         </cataloginventory>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_api>Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api</order_api>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

`Example/Webservices/Model/Order/Api.php` file:

```
<?php

  class Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api {
  protected function _initOrder($orderIncrementId) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');

    if(is_string($orderIncrementId)) {
        $order->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }
    } else {
        $order->load($orderIncrementId);
        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }
    }
    return $order;
}

public function cancel($orderIncrementId)
{
    Mage::log("Canel Order",null,'cancel-order.log');
    $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

    if (Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED == $order->getState()) {
        $this->_fault('status_not_changed');
    }
    try {
        $order->cancel();
        $order->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('status_not_changed', $e->getMessage());
    }
    if (Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED != $order->getState()) {
        $this->_fault('status_not_changed');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just speculating here but I think you are using the Api V2 version and that's why you end up in the original order api class.
For v2 api the class that is used is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2` that extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api`.
So your new class is never used. And the V2 class is still extending the old class.

What you need to do is to rewrite the v2 class also.
In your `config.xml` file, inside the `sales->rewrite` tag add this also

```
<order_api_v2>Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api_V2</order_api_v2>
```

and create the file `Example/Webservices/Model/Order/Api/V2.php` with this content

```
<?php
class Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api_V2 extends Example_Webservices_Model_Order_Api
{
}
```

Now you should be covered for both api v1 and v2.

Comment: Thanks Marius its working but can you please confirm extends class is 't core file

Comment: I don't understand your question. Let me explain again. You initially rewritten the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api`. This class is used by the Api V1. And your rewrite should work. But for Api V2 an other class is used (that extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api`). This means your rewrite will have no effect on V2. You need to rewrite the V2 class also and make it extend the class that rewrites the V1 class in order to make it work for both api versions.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just copy the file in this location. You dont even need a rewrite.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php
```

Now you can override any function.

Comment: Actually i approached that process, one of my client posted its not a standard procedure. thats why i want do in standard way

Comment: can you please explain where i done mistake in above script

Comment: No. Just no. Never do that if what you are trying to change is not an abstract class.

Comment: @Marius you are connected after long time. can you please explain briefly

Comment: @Marius - is there any explanation for the same? Seems its very much used approach.

Comment: yes please......

Comment: Maybe this explains it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25767/146

Comment: Well it explains... as we need to copy the whole file. no just a function and the upgraded part wont even execute because of this. But here is magento wiki also tells us to do the same even not just with an abstract class https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14024897